# Could not download versionedparcelable-1.1.0.aar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.0)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

My Gradle Configuration

compileSdkVersion 30

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-bin.zip

Updating the gradle plugin and gradle didn't solve my problem

Answer (score -1):

Adding this implementation to the build.gradle(app), solved my problem

```
implementation 'androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.1'
```